# Reset the projection of a GeoJSON file

Tags: python, geojson

I want to reproduce on a GIS like Mango, QGIS, Kibana ... the geodata to reproduce the map of this website. I don't know if it is a simple GeoJSON or

[image]

I tried a modification to [oktogen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252343/4764604) :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
splits = [item.split('=',1)[-1] for item in str(soup.script).split(';')]
filtered_splits = [item.replace('"','') for item in splits if 'json' in item and not 'xxx' in item]
links_to_jsons = ["https://data.electionsportal.ge" + item for item in    filtered_splits]
for item in links_to_jsons:
    r = requests.get(item)
    geojson = r.json()
    print(url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
    with open(item.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] +'.geojson', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(geojson, f)
```

And it looks like it was at least one of the two files and it looks like GeoJSON :

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': 
[[[4854546.154083, 5284008.666675], [4855951.745246, 5283252.476637], [4856871.642462, 5283565.511518], [4857608.037316, 5283222.205473], ...
..."properties": {"id": 69898, "parent_id": null, "common_id": "Georgia", "common_name": "Georgia", "has_children": true, "shape_type_id": 1, "shape_type_name": "Country", "value": "No Data", "color": null, "title_location": "Country: Georgia"}}]}
```

But when importing it to Kibana I have the following layer:

[image]

I think the problem is a projection error. Kibana must wait to give the project on a map of the world and these were made for a map of borders in the Caucasus.

On Mapbox I have the following error:

```
Upload errored a few seconds ago
Close
1-8q9493
bounds west value must be between -360 and 360
```

I don't know how to reset the projection on a GeoJSON file.

However, in QGis everything looks perfect:

[image]

So I know I can reproject from QGis ...

Comment: Shapefiles for the map are available: "All of the original shapefiles outlining electoral geographic boundaries were obtained from the Caucasus Research Resource Center (CRRC)"  search http://crrc.ge/ka/

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, this site can’t be reached

Comment: And it is badly designed as som layers hide the links of some folders

Comment: contact CRRC-Georgia directly https://caucasusbarometer.org/en/about/

Comment: you need to set the projection. By default it is assumed to be 4326, but obviously the coordinates are in a different CRS

Comment: @JGH I understand. However, do you know how I can find the right one?

Comment: You can check what they use on the original website, or see if they make sense using the "common projection for this area" or at last in 3857

Comment: @JGH sure! But how can I check that? In the file? I have added the end of it. Should I add something like `"type": "proj4"` in `"properties"`?

Comment: The coordinates look like EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator).

Comment: @JGH GeoJSON is not EPSG::4326 it's CRS:84 (different coordinate order)

Comment: @mkennedy thanks for your insight. How can I change it and too what format?